# short exact sequence of profinite groups

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups, profinite-groups, short-exact-sequences

Let $A\rightarrow B\rightarrow B/A$ be a short exact sequence of topological groups. Is it true that if there exists a continuous function $B/A\rightarrow B$ (of underlying spaces) such that the composition  $B/A\rightarrow B\rightarrow B/A$ is the identity  then  $A\times B/A$ is homeomorphic  to $B$ as topological space?

I'm mostly interested in the case of profinite groups.

Comment: Short exact sequence of topological sequence has to be defined carefully: the kernel is endowed with the induced topology and the quotient with the quotient topology.

Comment: I think this is true for all topological groups. Call your function $s$, and define $f:A\times B/A\rightarrow B$ by $f(a,x)=a.s(x)$, $g:B\rightarrow A\times B/A$ by $g(b)= (b.s(\bar{b})^{-1},\bar{b})$. They are inverse of each other, and clearly continuous.

Comment: (I misread the question first. This is indeed a trivial exercise.)